# Reason for end of file

Tags: c, file

For a project I have to translate a made up assembly language into memory locations and op codes. I need to parse the file twice and I used strtok() to do this. However, my program doesn't reach the second loop. (I put a print statement towards the beginning so I am pretty sure it doesn't reach it.) My thought was that the pointer was at the end of the file, so I tried putting rewind(filename) and fseek(filename, 0, SEEK_SET), however neither seemed to solve the problem. Any thoughts? Thanks.

EDIT: here's some code (code for second pass)

```
j=1, i=0;
/*SECOND PASS*/
fseek(opcode,0,SEEK_SET);
char string[5];
while((fgets(str, buffer, file))!=NULL){/*getting line*/
printf("it got here. yup.");
fputs(memLoc(j-1), opcode); /*inserts the location in memory to file*/
fputs(" ", opcode);/*puts a space in the file*/ 

int state=0; /*state to see if on first or second part of code*/

for(i=0; i<buffer; i++){ /*gets rid of extra new line chars*/
    if(str[i]=='\n'){
    str[i]= '\0';
    break;
    }
}
cp = xerox(str);
token = strtok(cp, delimiters);
printf("%s ",token);
/*if it's not a label, find corresponding opcode and insert into file,
switch state, if it's a label, don't switch state*/
    if((token!=NULL)&&token[strlen(token)-1]!=':'){
        fputs(findOpCode(token), opcode);
        state=1;
    }
    else state=0;

/*if it should be an opcode, insert corresponding opcode into file,
if it should be a location, find and insert where it should be*/
    for (;token = strtok(NULL, delimiters);){
    printf("%s ",token);
        if(token!=NULL)
            if(state==0){
            fputs(findOpCode(token), opcode);
            }

            else if(state==1){
            fputs(locate(token, fIndex), opcode);
            }
        }
    j++;
    fputc('\n', opcode);/*next line*/
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: you'll get much better answers if you post the relevant parts of the code having the issue.

Comment: Some code would really help here. Your best bet is to post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Take your code, boil it down to the bare minimum necessary to create the strange behavior, and post that.

Comment: The best thing you can do for yourself is to learn how to use a debugger on whatever platform you are coding for. Start a debug session and step through your code, inspecting variables and their values at key points in the code.

While someone here on SO can probably point out the bug to you, if you really want to add to your skills as a programmer (and debugging is a necessary one at that) it is a much better thing to learn to use your debugger.

Comment: Can you recommend a good gdb tutorial? I know basic debugging, but I don't know how to use it with multiple files and parsing txt files.

Comment: Sams see this Q: [What is a good place to learn Debugging techniques & GDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6222517/3534)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you rewinding the wrong file? Don't you want to rewind the file you are reading from and parsing? If so, it should be:

```
fseek(file,0,SEEK_SET);
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing I'd do is add error checking to your fseek:

```
if (fseek(opcode,0,SEEK_SET) == -1) {
    perror("fseek");
    exit(1);
}
```

That should give you more information.